# Scala Regex Parser throws weird error

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I have a simple RegexParser that matches {key}={value} repeating for several times:

```
object CommandOptionsParser extends RegexParsers {
  private val key: Parser[String] = "[^= ]+".r
  private val value: Parser[String] = "[^ ]*".r

  val pair: Parser[Option[(String, Option[String])]] =
    (key ~ ("=".r ~> value).?).? ^^ {
      case None => None
      case Some(k ~ v) => Some(k.trim -> v.map(_.trim))
    }

  val pairs: Parser[Map[String, Option[String]]] = phrase(repsep(pair, whiteSpace)) ^^ {
    case v =>
      Map(v.flatten: _*)
  }

  def apply(input: String): Map[String, Option[String]] = parseAll(pairs, input) match {
    case Success(plan, _) => plan
    case x => sys.error(x.toString)
  }
}
```

However the matching of value seems to fail on more than 1 capturing groups (despite that the regex doesn't limit it). when I try to match against "token=abc again=abc", I have the following error:

```
[1.11] failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `a' found

token=abc again=abc'
          ^
```

Why RegexParser has such strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for your unexpected behavior is quite easy, just change the value of `skipWhitespace`:

```
object CommandOptionsParser extends RegexParsers {
  override val skipWhitespace = false
```

From description of `RegexParsers`:

> The parsing methods call the method `skipWhitespace` (defaults to
>   `true`) and, if true, skip any whitespace before each parser is
>   called.

So, what happened, your first `pair` was matched, then `whiteSpace` was skipped and then, as `repsep` couldn't find another whitespace separator, it just assumed that parsing is over, hence that "\z" expected.

Also, I can't help but note that the whole Parser approach for such simple task seems overcomplicated, simple regexps would suffice.

---

**UPD**: Also your parsers can be a bit simpler:

```
  val pair: Parser[Option[(String, Option[String])]] =
    (key ~ ("=" ~> value).?).? ^^ (_.map {case (k ~ v) => k.trim -> v.map(_.trim)})

  val pairs: Parser[Map[String, Option[String]]] = phrase(repsep(pair, whiteSpace)) ^^
    { l => Map(l.flatten: _*)}
```